# IE 'x' icon is not clearing the counter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have created Angular directive that counts character for inputs and text area, its working as expected, but only Problem that was raised by user is when they clear input using IE 'x' icon it does not clear out the count it should set back to `mayLength` of 256. How can i resolve this issue for IE ?

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
        ng-model="input.searchValue" placeholder="Enter search item"
        maxlength="256" name={{$index}}
        data-tooltip-html-unsafe="<div>{{256 - input.searchValue.length}} characters left</div>"
        tooltip-trigger="{{{true: 'focus', false: 'never'}[ input.searchValue.length >= 0 || input.searchValue.length == null ]}}"
        tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-class = "bluefill"/>
</div>
```

directive.js

```
angular.module('myMaxlength', []).directive('myMaxlength', function () {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            attrs.$set('ngTrim', 'false');
            var maxlength = parseInt(attrs.myMaxlength, 10);
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                if (value.length > maxlength) {
                    value = value.substr(0, maxlength);
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(value);
                    ctrl.$render();
                }
                return value;

            });

        }
    };
});
```